# Action Bar collapseActionView vs Never options

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Can someone explain the difference between using `collapseActionView` and `never` for the ActionBar `showAsAction` attribute?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the documentation, the "never" attribute makes it so the button is never placed in the action bar, [Menu Resource](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/menu-resource.html). The "collapseActionView" allows the button to be shown but as a widget. This button can be dynamic, like a search button that expands. See here for better explanation: [Action Bar Adding Action View](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).